# Uploading specific file to a folder (FTP) in java

Tags: java, file, ftp, transfer

Good Day,

I just need you help regarding on my program.. basically my program is intend to transfer files or copy files from the local pc and transfer it to a remote site (FTP)
Here is my code:

```
FTPClient destFtpClient = new FTPClient();
                    destFtpClient.connect(destIPAddressCom, intPort);
                    destFtpClient.login(destFtpID, destFtpPwd);
                    destFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                    destFtpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                    String newRoot = recipeRoot.toString();
                    File[] transFiles = new File(newRoot).listFiles();
                        for(File file : transFiles) {
                            for(int i = 0; i < transFiles.length; i++){
                            File destFile = new File(destTest); //destination path
                            //File newDestFile = new File(destFile +File.separator+file.getName()); // destination path with the file
                            FileInputStream fisFile = new FileInputStream(destFile);
                            destFtpClient.storeFile(file.getName(), fisFile);
                            fisFile.close();
                        }
                    }
```

I've got an error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Test (The specified path is invalid)

but the destination folder is `Test` 
this is the specific folder `/Test/file`
I hop you can help regarding on this one. Thank you in advance!

**EDITED**

I tried to used what @Whome said and on the first run it works then suddenly after trying to rerun it does not work and got the same error above.

```
destFtpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("//Test");
                                destFtpClient.makeDirectory("//Test");
                                File destFile = new File(destTest);
                                FileInputStream fisFile = new FileInputStream(p1dest);
                                destFtpClient.storeFile(file.getName(), fisFile);
```

Comment: Do you have access to /Test? Also, is your program sending a command for '\Test' or '/Test'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ftpclient.changeWorkingDirectory("/Test")` before uploading files and possibly leading `makeDirectory("/Test")`. Why do you have foreach and for(idx) loops? Once your working directory is changed then upload just using a filename without a full path.

Comment: Thank you for answering.. I'll try to work on what you said.. I'm just gonna tell you if its working or not, again thanks!

Comment: sorry to disturb you again but its already working and then suddenly when i try to rerun it again it does not work... do you have any ideas what happen on this case?